# NSString within a link

Tags: uiwebview, nsstring, hyperlink

I have a UIWebView that loads a link, http://www.google.com/a/datacommsales.net. But I want to have the datacommsales.net part interchangable. What I would like it to be is http://www.google.com/a/stringOne, stringOne being the NSString, so I can set the value of the string and change the link without editing the code. But the link is inside quotes, @"http://www.google.com/a/datacommsales.net", so it doesn't recognize the string. How could I include the string's value as part of the link? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT

To be a little more specific, here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)refreshNow:(id)sender
```

{

```
NSString *variablePart = @"secondpart.com";
NSString *page = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"google.com/a/variablePart/docs"];

[webView loadHTMLString:page baseURL:nil];
```

}

How would I put the string variablePart in the link like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean just something like

```
NSString *variablePart = @"secondpart.com";
NSString *url = [@"http://www.google.com/" stringByAppendingString:variablePart];
```

EDIT:

```
NSString *variablePart = @"secondpart.com";
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"google.com/a/%@/docs", variablePart];
```

Comment: Thanks. Kind of what I'm looking for. But to be a little more specific, here's my code:
- (IBAction)refreshNow:(id)sender
{
 
 NSString *variablePart = @"secondpart.com";
 NSString *page = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"google.com/a/variablePart/docs"];
 
 [webView loadHTMLString:page baseURL:nil];
How would I put the string variablePart in the link like that?

Answer (score 1):

Checks the NSString stringWithFormat method... Or explain a little more how you do your stuff...